# What is the advantage of Replace over Drop while changing a package in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What are the advantages of using `create or replace package` to change a package in Oracle PL/SQL over `drop` and `create`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `"A"` has a package `pkg_tst`. They have granted privileges on it to another user, "B". They also have a procedure `p1` which depends on the package.

```
SQL> select * from user_tab_privs made where table_name = 'PKG_TST';

GRANTEE OWNER   TABLE_NAME GRANTOR PRIVILE GRA HIE
------- ------- ---------- ------- ------- --- ---
B       A       PKG_TST    A       EXECUTE NO  NO

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'P1';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL>
```

Now if  User `"A"` recreates the package any grants remain in place and the dependency is still valid (thanks [Fine-grained dependency management](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_dependencies.htm#ADFNS99992)!)

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_tst as
  2    procedure p1;
  3  end pkg_tst;
  4  /
Package created.

SQL> select * from user_tab_privs made where table_name = 'PKG_TST';

GRANTEE OWNER   TABLE_NAME GRANTOR PRIVILE GRA HIE
------- ------- ---------- ------- ------- --- ---
B       A       PKG_TST    A       EXECUTE NO  NO

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'P1';

STATUS
-------
VALID

SQL>
```

Compare this with what happens when they drop the package and create it afresh.

```
SQL> drop package pkg_tst;

Package dropped.

SQL> create or replace package pkg_tst as
  2     procedure p1;
  3  end pkg_tst;
  4  /
Package created.

SQL>create or replace package body pkg_tst as
  2    procedure p1 
  3    is
  4    begin
  5      dbms_output.put_line($$plsql_unit||' works!');
  6    end p1;
  7  end;
  8  /
Package body created.

SQL> select * from user_tab_privs made where table_name = 'PKG_TST';

no rows selected

SQL> select status from user_objects where object_name = 'P1';

STATUS
-------
INVALID

SQL>
```

So the benefits of using `create or replace package` over `drop package` and `create package` are clear. It minimises the impact of deploying code changes on other parts of the application:

- we don't need to re-issue grants on the package
- we don't need to recompile dependent program units

Answer (score 1):

Lets say:
1) You created package;
2) You modified it. Now, what do you do? Package was already created, so in order for your changes to me saved, you have to drop it and then create in again. You do this manually. But with "create or replace" you dont have to do it. You just modify and hit compile - changes will be always saved. Its like a save with refresh function. Conclusion - oracle saves your precious time, that you dont have to do additional time consuming steps.

Answer (score 0):

By REPLACING instead of DROPPING & CREATING you have less problems with other packages/funcs/procs that depend on the package. If you drop these will become invalid.